# SQL STUFF and CASE expression and joined tables

Tags: sql-server, case, ssms, for-xml-path

First time poster, so apologies if I have not detailed everything as required! Had a good search for any similar questions but unable to locate.

I have been asked to write a query which shows clients that are linked to other clients by being sat in the same vehicle -

```
Ref  Ref2   
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       3
2       4
```

Simply put, client 1,2,3 and 4 are all in the same vehicle and so have a row in a table linking them together.

I have been tasked with adding to a report, details of the linked file, within the same row as the rest of my query. I have done this by using the stuff function, found from another question on here:

```
select distinct r.ref
, stuff(
(select ','+r2.ref2 as [text()]
from related r
where r2.ref = r.ref 
for xml path ('')
),1,1,' ') as [linked]
from related r2
```

which shows in row 1 : 2,3,4 and this works fine.

What I need to do is the same, but to detail the client's position within the vehicle, using the same theory as above e.g.

```
Ref |Linked | Driver/Passenger
1 |   2,3,4 |  D,P,P,P
```

Here is the query as I have adapted it using a CASE expression - I think my join is one of the issues, and have tried to include elsewhere but to no avail:

```
select distinct r.ref
, stuff(
(select ','+CASE WHEN s.status = 'DRV' THEN 'D' WHEN 
s.status = 'PASVEC' THEN 'P' WHEN s.status = 'OWNND' THEN 'P' ELSE '' END [text()]
from status s
where s.ref = r.ref2 -- Looking at the ref of the linked case
for xml path ('')),1,1,' ') as [D/P]
from related r
```

Edit:

The output I am getting is a list of all of the related cases i.e.

```
Ref | D/P
1   | D
2   | P
3   | P
4   | P
```

No errors output.

I have also tried an inner join in the from statement.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: One thing that may help is doing a proper join in the from Statement. FROM Satus S INNER JOIN <Other table name> R ON s.ref = r.ref2. Does  the query give you any errors? Could you post a sample of the output?

Comment: It sounds there is something not being returned the way you want it to. However, you don't tell us what the problem is. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Apologies - updated to detail output!

Comment: @Laing111 return `related r` to the subquery - just like in your first attempt. It should be `select ..., (from related r inner join status for xml) from related`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want another representation of the Main/Linked status of the person, can you not just have a slightly different `FOR XML`?

```
declare @t table(r int, r2 int, PDstatus nvarchar(50));
insert into @t values
 (1,2,'DRV')
,(1,3,'PASVEC')
,(1,4,'DRV')
,(2,1,'DRV')
,(2,3,'OWNND');

select d.r
        ,stuff((select ', ' + cast(p.r2 as nvarchar(10))
                 from @t p
                 where d.r = p.r
                 for xml path('')
                 )
            ,1,2,''
            ) as Linked

        -- This assumes the Main record is always the driver?
        ,'D' + (select case p.PDstatus when 'DRV' then ', D'
                                       when 'OWNND' then ', P'
                                       when 'PASVEC' then ', P'
                        else ', X'
                        end
                 from @t p
                 where d.r = p.r
                 for xml path('')
                ) as DP
from @t d;
```

Output:

```
r   |Linked  |DP
1   |2, 3, 4 |D, D, P, D
1   |2, 3, 4 |D, D, P, D
1   |2, 3, 4 |D, D, P, D
2   |1, 3    |D, D, P
2   |1, 3    |D, D, P
```